# Passport outer cover with slight damage

Tags: passports, visa-refusals, international-travel, schengen-visas

I need to travel to Germany this coming January 14th for an interview. The travel is only for 4 days. I have submitted all the relevant and supporting documents for getting the travel schengen visa. When I submitted my passport to VFS they told me the passport is damaged. But the damage is only to the over cover towards to the edges like as shown below and all the inner pages and information are perfectly fine. VFS has taken my application but told me that they cant guarantee. The tickets are all booked using this passport number so I cannot apply for a new one at this moment of time

[image]

Like to know whether my application will be accepted or rejected.

Comment: That the tickets are booked with that passport number does not mean that you cannot replace your passport.  You can give the new passport number when you get it, or when you check in for the flight.

Comment: @phoog is there any chance of rejection happens for my case

Comment: Not necessarily. They will check the bindings and the pages thoroughly for any discrepancy and if nothing is amiss they won't bother.

Comment: There is always a chance of rejection.

Comment: Did you get your visa? I want to know the final result.

Comment: Yes I got the visa

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use a passport cover. I’ve used a passport with a cover in Europe literally tens of times and nobody ever removed it.

It mainly depends on the agent you’ll meet but there’s no reason not to try to avoid the discussion completely.

Comment: I don't think your answer is generally applicable. I have a cover for my passport and had to remove it every single time for the pass control when flying or applying for a visa. That's about 30 out of 30 times in the last 15 years on routes between EU, UK, US and Russia. Also, pass controls within Europe are virtually non-existent and can't be compared to getting a visa.

Comment: @EwigeStudentin my experience shows otherwise but I did EU only (around 50 flights in the last year, mostly Italy and Greece)The wear in the passport should not be a problem in any case, as long as the security features are not worn. As far as I’m concerned there are none on the cover.

Comment: @EwigeStudentin a passport cover will go a long way toward reducing the amount of damage to the passport in the first place, however.